# Placing User ID's within Routes with Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I currently have a default devise set up and wanting to put the user id's within my logged in routes and leave the others alone such as Welcome,FAQ, About us etc.

Such as
www.example.com/*user-id*/offers

My Current Routes File

```
  devise_for :users

  mount RailsAdmin::Engine => '/admin', as: 'rails_admin'

  resources :offers do
    member do
       put :tourcomplete
    end   
  end

  resources :categories, only: :show

  root 'welcome#index'

  get '/balance', to: 'balance#show', as: 'balance'

  patch '/balance', to: 'balance#paypal', as: 'balance_paypal'

  patch '/withdraw', to: 'balance#withdraw', as: 'balance_withdraw'
```

I can't find any docs on this and my previous answer to a similar question was very vague and not helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use a nested routes:

```
resources :users do
  resources :offers do
    member do
       put :tourcomplete
    end   
  end
end
```

so now your routes will be `/users/:id/offers`, run rake routes to check your routes.

if you want to exclude `users` then you will have to specify the route yourself:

```
match ':user_id/offers' => 'offers#index'
```

Comment: I'm trying to put it in the routes? Not access it via the view

Comment: let us know why may be its not the best way to do what are  you trying to do.

Comment: I'm trying to put the User-id within my routes e.g. www.hello.com/user-id/offers, your answer is describing how to put user-id within my views html.

Comment: Thanks Mohamed, is there anyway to remove /users/?

Comment: Getting  undefined local variable or method `user_offers'

def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    user_offers
  end

Comment: i'm not sure where you use user_offers but it should be `user_offers_path` and if you using the url without users then you will need to use `as` to specify path name like: `match ':user_id/offers' => 'offers#index', as: 'user_offers'`